# Gunicorn not starting automatically

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, flask, centos, gunicorn

I've created a flask application. I'm trying to deploy it into the Production with WSGI Gunicorn server and Nginx reverse proxy in Centos 7. The following is my project working directory.

```
projet
    |--templates
       |--static
   |---app.py
   |---wsgi.py
```

And here I'm using virtual environment "my_app". When I'm going to the project working folder and running the app by 
`gunicorn wsgi:app` 
I'm able to see the results in the webpage. But when I close the system, I'm getting `502 Bad GateWay`. Which means everytime I need to manually run the gunicorn command to be able see the results in the webpage. But I want to start it automatically.For this, I'm creating a service file with the help of systemd. The following are the configuration files for both Nginx and Gunicorn.

In /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskapp.conf

```
server{
     listen 80;
     server_name xxxx.xxx.xx.xx;
     access_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
     uwsgi_read_timeout 120;

     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }


     location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix://home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/pre_owned_model/evaluation_calculator/gunicorn.sock;
        #proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     }
}
```

In /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=centos
Group=centos
RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn
WorkingDirectory=/home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/pre_owned_model/evaluation_calculator
ExecStart=/home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/my_app/bin/gunicorn  --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/pre_owned_model/evaluation_calculator/gunicorn.sock -m 007 wsgi:app
ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID
ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID
TimeoutStopSec=3
PrivateTmp=true
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

However I'm not getting the results of what I'm expecting. Everytime I'm getting `502 Bad Gateway` even after creating the service. Can anyone explain How I can achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you.

Comment: can you show your corresponding `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` file?

Comment: Hi, gunicorn.socket file is completely empty when I reload the systemctl.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/deploy.html
You need a file `/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket` which corresponds to your gunicorn.service

It should contain the following:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/pre_owned_model/evaluation_calculator/gunicorn.sock
# Our service won't need permissions for the socket, since it
# inherits the file descriptor by socket activation
# only the nginx daemon will need access to the socket
User=centos
# Optionally restrict the socket permissions even more.
# Mode=600

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

After Creating the file you most likely need to reload systemd with:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

To enable the socket you have also to run the command

`systemctl enable --now gunicorn.socket`

This is going to start the service when the first connection to your socket starts.

Comment: Hi, Thank you. I followed the above steps. But I got the socket file error. The error is " [crit] 10187#0: *21 connect() to unix:/home/centos/Python-3.6.4/my_flask_app/pre_owned_model/evaluation_calculator/gunicorn.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream ". Could you explain why I got this error.

Comment: seems that your nginx user cannot access the socket.